# Fortran MPI and OpenMP additional threads

Tags: multithreading, fortran, mpi, openmp

I have a code that is already paralleled by MPI. Every MPI process have to do a lot of calculations on the grid. The code looks something like this:

```
do i=starti,stopi
  call function1(input1(i),output1)
  call function1(input2(i+1),output2)
  call function1(input3(i+2,output3)
  call solve(output1,output2,output3,OUTPUT(i))
end do
```

Where MPI have different ranges of starti and stopi. For example for 2 processes I have:

```
 process 1 starti=1  , stopi=100
 process 2 starti=101 , stopi=200
```

This is working very nice but I want to use OpenMP to speed thing up a little bit. Modified code looks like this:

```
do i=starti,stopi
  !$OMP PARALLEL SECTIONS
  !$OMP SECTION
  call function1(input1(i),output1)
  !$OMP SECTION
  call function1(input2(i+1),output2)
  !$OMP SECTION
  call function1(input3(i+2),output3)
  !$OMP END PARALLEL SECTIONS
  call solve(output1,output2,output3,OUTPUT(i))
end do
```

But when I run this code with 2 MPI Processes and 3 OpenMP threads it is 2x slower than pure MPI. The CPU is not the case as I have 4 cores/ 8 threads CPU. 
Why is that?

Comment: Are you interested in parallelism or concurrency? They're not the same thing.

Comment: You must show more code. The function at least.

Comment: Did you check if you hadn't MPI process to core pinning activated? If so, it is likely that each MPI process is restricted to use a single core of your machine. This will be inherited by the OpenMP threads of the MPI processes, which will therefore compete to the single core they are allowed to use, while leaving the other cores idle... Just a guess, but a very possible one.